# Grid layout cant get it right xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hi I am using xamarin forms and I would like to use the grid more rather than nesting stacklayouts.

I have to say that even though I have read the microsoft explanation multiple times "auto vs "*"
i do get confused and I wish I could find a simple explanation

See the pic below I would like the amount to be close the star icon but I get below, where the amount is far from the icon.I even put colors to see where things are. Any suggestions?

```
  <Frame Margin="0,0,0,10"  CornerRadius="10" BorderColor="Red">
                <Grid >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Yellow" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Long description message"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" BackgroundColor="Aqua" Text="28/1/2019" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
                    <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Coral" Source="star.png" HorizontalOptions="Start"></Image>
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="CornflowerBlue" Text="£ 11.000" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" BackgroundColor="DarkCyan" Text="£33,565.45" FontSize="16" VerticalTextAlignment="End" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Auto` means (in your case of column width) that it is going to take the width required by the largest element of the specific column as the column width. In your example, the second column is no larger than what *£ 11.000* requires on the screen. If you would write *£ 11.000.000* the 2nd column width would automatically increase and adapt to this text and then both columns 1 and 3 would be equally smaller.

`*` or *star* means that it's going to split the remaining space available between the total amount of stars set up in all width properties. For instance given a grid with 2 columns: if column 1 width equals to `*` (shortcurt for 1*) and column 2 width is also equals to `*` it will split up the screen right into the middle and both width would be equals. If 1st column width equals to `2*` and 2nd width equals to `*`, 1st column will use 2/3 of screen width and 2nd column will use the remaining 1/3. If 1st column width equals to `3*` and 2nd width equals to `*`, 1st column will use 3/4 (75%) of screen width and 2nd column will use the remaining 1/4. And so on...

So regarding your code you can *read* it as the following: First it set up automatically 2nd column width based on the largest element of the column (in your case *£ 11.000*) then since you have 2 columns left with `*` as the width it will split up the remaining space into 2 equals width. This is why the number is not next to the picture, because of the '*' of the first column.

To fix this, you just need to set the 1st column width to `Auto` and 2nd column to `*`:

```
<Frame Margin="0,0,0,10"  CornerRadius="10" BorderColor="Red">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Yellow" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Long description message"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" BackgroundColor="Aqua" Text="28/1/2019" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
        <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Coral" Source="star.png" HorizontalOptions="Start"></Image>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="CornflowerBlue" Text="£ 11.000" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" BackgroundColor="DarkCyan" Text="£33,565.45" FontSize="16" VerticalTextAlignment="End" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
    </Grid>
</Frame>
```